# Add a button to the Camera Toolbar on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using a UIImagePickerController subclass to take photos in my app.

The toolbar for the camera has a cancel button and a photo button on it. I would also like to add another button on the right.

I have tried to add a UIBarButtonItem to the subclass's toolbar, but that doesn't work. I have also tried to make a UIToolbar that looks like the camera toolbar, so I can just overlay a toolbar with one button invisibly, but I can't seem to match the style of the camera toolbar.

Any ideas on how to add a button to the camera toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant customize the UIImagePickerController tool bar  just like that, what you have to do is work with with the overlay view in the UIImagePickerController which allows you to specify a view to use for the  picker instead of  the  default one, here is a link with [information about this overlayview property of  the  UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView)